# What is the benefit of having user defined return type over predefined datatype for a method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the benefit of having user defined like class,interface,struct name as return type over predefined datatype for a method?
It would be more helpful if someone give me an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if *you* gave an example, too, because it's not clear at all what you are asking.

Comment: There is no benefit, it just depends on whether a defined type is necessary if a predefined type cannot convey the information you wish to return.

Answer (score 2):

The benefit is that if you'll ever want to change the return type, or return another value in addition to the one you're already returning, you won't have to change the code using the method.

It is a good practice, in general, a rule of thumb if you'd like. However, it is not very common in most project, and only become such when such a change is actually needed, and then refactoring is done.

The reason for that is that there is overhead to such design - too many classes and structures added to the project, and most of the time you can't really tell when to reuse such a wrapping class in another method and when to create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The main benefit is that making changes afterward could be done as a non-breaking change. Suppose you have method:

```
public KeyValuePair<int, String> GetMyStuff(int searchByA, string searchByB)
{
    KeyValuePair<int, String> result = null;
    //find result using parameters;
    return result;
}
```

Then let's imagine you get new requirements that you should also return the `IsActive` property and should be able to search by it. It would not fit to current return type so the method signature should be changed. to add extra parameter fore searching is similar - API change is a breaking change and all existing callers should be refactored even if they do not need the new feature.

A better approach is to have separate types/interfaces to encapsulate the concept of input and output. For example:

```
public class StuffSearchInput
{
    int ByA { get; set; }
    int ByB { get; set; }
}
public class StuffSearchOutput
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    String Name { get; set; }
}
public StuffSearchOutput GetMyStuff(StuffSearchInput arguments)
{
    StuffSearchOutput result = null;
    //find result using arguments;
    return result;
}
```

Now you can simply add the `IsActive` property to `StuffSearchInput` and `StuffSearchOutput`, add extra logic to method body and you have met the requirements without breaking any existing callers (possibly hundreds on locations). The method signature remains unchanged and it can still serve all the old callers. Example:

```
public class StuffSearchInput
{
    int ByA { get; set; }
    int ByB { get; set; }
    Boolean? ByIsActive { get; set; }
}
public class StuffSearchOutput
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    String Name { get; set; }
    Boolean ByIsActive { get; set; }
}
public StuffSearchOutput GetMyStuff(StuffSearchInput arguments)
{
    StuffSearchOutput result = null;
    //find result using arguments, and also fill the IsActive field.
    return result;
}
```

Using interfaces would add even more freedom to vary allowed input/output. For example, requiring `IEnumerable<T>` as input would allow you to pass in anything from `List<T>` to `Collection<T>` to LINQ output - whatever is more convenient to callers.

Answer (score 2):

User defined types can be more expressive of your design, and more strongly typed.

If your return type can be stored in a built in type, and if you're not designing an API and therefor API breaking changes are not something you have to worry about, and if you don't need the extra expression/strong typing, then just go with the built in type, as it can be changed later, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's all about how sure you are what do you want? If you are convinced that your application logic requires customized set of information to be returned and it's essential then you must do it. If you are not sure then try to avoid unnecessary overhead. Remember you always have a liberty to use polymorphism especially overloading. Although you will require different signature stamp changing Type of parameters, number of parameters ideally. And if you have a situation where you can't overload because neither Type nor number of parameters can be changed due to your design and you have at-least two parameters, with different types change their ordinal positions and you are through. Not the best but doable. Here are few examples:

```
public class something
{
    public int MyScore(int subjectID, int attendance, string class name)
    {
        //return score
    }
   public int[] MyScore(int subjectID, int attendance, string class name, bool includeSportScore)
    {
        //return general and sports score here as array
    }
    public ScoreQuality MyScore(string xlassName,int subjectID, int attendance)
   {
       //return grade instead of number example of changing ordinal position
   }

   public enum ScoreQuaity
   {Average, Poor, Excellent}
}
```